# How can I store edited pictures with iPhoto for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, applications, photos.app, photos

Im a bit surprise about few things in IPhoto for iPhone.

1) I cant create albums or group pictures into events. Is it true?

2) Once Ive dited few photos there isnt an easy way to save them i to my photo library. in the share menu, there is "Camera Roll", however it allows you the export 1 picture per ime (differently from other sharing options) and it takes ages.

This is not the same behavior I have on iPhoto for mac: when I edit a pic on mac the edited pictures replace the original ones (and they are automatically stored in my photo library and shared among all devices).

Thanks
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create albums directly on the iPhone.

1. Go into Camera Roll
2. Click the share icon in the upper right corner
3. Select all the photos you'd like to add to a new album
4. Select "Add To" and then "New Album"

When it comes to edited images I guess it depends on how you edit them. Most programs offer to save a new copy of the image and thus keep the original and new one. I guess it's possible that some programs also offer to replace the original. Regardless, when you create new albums just choose the edit image.